# selenium , vba element is not Interactable

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

```
<div id="j_idt248" class="ui-confirm-dialog ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-hidden-container ui-dialog-rtl" role="dialog" ; display: block;">
<button id="j_idt250" name="j_idt250" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-confirmdialog-yes" type="button">
```

This div `display` is `block` and I can't access it. I see this error

```
element is not Interactable
```

This is my code:

```
bot.FindElementByName("j_idt250").Click
```

Comment: Plenty of previous posts here with that same error message - have you tried any of the fixes in those posts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what element your code is finding because the HTML you posted doesn't have an element with a name "j_idt249" but it does have an ID with that name. Change your find method to by ID and it will match the HTML you posted.

Comment: Dear i have a button in that div with this id

Comment: I think my problem only is for    display : block      because i get another elements very easy , but in this div i cant

Comment: Your posted code is searching by NAME not ID. Your updated HTML contains a name of "j_idt250" NOT "j_idt249" as is in your code. If your code and/or HTML is not correct, you need to update your question.

Comment: `display:block` has nothing to do with not visible. See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#outside).

Comment: Open the devtools in Chrome and run `$$("#j_idt250")` and see if returns any elements. If it find one or more, click on the first one and see where it is on the page... is it visible? There may be more than one element with that ID but the first one is not visible, etc.

Comment: You may also need to wait for clickable... it may a little time to load that part of the page and for the button to become enabled.